# Where are Hibernate 5 properties documented?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, hibernate-5.x

Hibernate 3 and 4 used to document the available configuration properties:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional

The documentation for Hibernate 5 (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/) does not contain anything similar. Is it just not ready?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional

Comment: Interesting. Your link is from July 2015 and it corresponds to 5.0.0.CR2. The link from the official website is from Jan 2016 and corresponds to 5.0.7.Final. So it was removed then?

Comment: Also comparing the size of the 2 versions, the HTML file went from 1.57MB down to 703KB. Was half of the documentation really obsolete and unnecessary?

Comment: My link is to manual, you are referring to user guide.

Comment: The documentation home page for 5.0 does not list any Manual, just the User Guide: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.0/ Is it missing? On the other hand, the documentation home page for 4.3 does not list any User Guide, just the Manual: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/4.3/. So, in 5.0 will there be both a User Guide (present) and a Manual (currently missing)? Or is the User Guide replacing the Manual in 5.0?

Comment: There are different kinds of docs on jboss site: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/ I am not sure how docs on hibernate.org are classified though.

Comment: It looks to me like the manual was removed. Even on the jboss site, the manual hasn't been updated since July 2015 while all other pieces of documentation are current as of Jan 2016. To ask this differently, where is the manual for 5.0.7?

Comment: The documentation for every release are supplied with the release itself. You can download Hibernate's older version of your choice from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-orm/ and the documentations are available in hibernate-release-5.0.4.Final.zip\hibernate-release-5.0.4.Final\documentation\userGuide

These are the same like the online user guide.

Comment: I'm not looking for older documentation. The downloaded version is the same as the one on the web site. During this conversation I realized that the "Manual" from the previous version was replaced by a "User Guide" which is half the size and among others it also misses the documentation for the configuration properties. If all this a mistake on my side answer this question: Where are the configuration properties documented in the Hibernate 5.0.7 release? Hibernate website, Jboss website, downloadable version, anywhere ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I joined the Hibernate team, my first task was to rewrite the entire Hibernate User Guide. So, starting from Hibernate 5.1, there's a new [section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations) dedicated to Hibernate configurations.

Enjoy reading it!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This is no longer relevant, the problem was resolved.

Based on the discussion in the comments, it looks like the comprehensive "Manual" from 4.3 was replaced in 5.0 with a more limited "User Guide" which among other things does not document the configuration properties. To give you an idea about the changes, the HTML for the 5.0 "User Guide" is about half the size of the 4.3 "Manual".